# Node JS Pass variables to pug template's JavaScript and html sections

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I have the following route and it passes a serires of variables to the pug template.

**items.js route**

```
router.get('/edit/:itemObjectId', async function(req, res, next) {
    var itemObjectId = req.params.itemObjectId;
    var equipmentCategoryArr = [];
    var lifeExpectancyArr = [];
    var businessUnitResponsibleArr = [];
    var item = undefined;

    try {
        item = await db_item.getItem(itemObjectId);

        // Where item["result"] is either undefined or a JavaScript Object. E.g. {"createdAt":"2018-11-07T04:07:44.587Z","updatedAt":"2018-11-07T04:25:18.526Z","item_name":"GM Portable","manufacturer":"GM"}
        res.render('editItem', {
            title: 'Edit item details', // Give a title to our page
            item: item["result"],
            equipmentCategoryArr: req.app.locals.equipmentCategoryArr,
            lifeExpectancyArr: req.app.locals.lifeExpectancyArr,
            businessUnitResponsibleArr: req.app.locals.businessUnitResponsibleArr
        });
    } catch (err) {
        return Promise.reject(JSON.stringify({ "Error": err }));
    }
});
```

On my `editItem.pug` page, I need to pass the variables of an item into the javascript section and a series of input boxes or labels.

**editItem.pug**

```
extends layout
block extraScript
    script.
        $(document).ready(function(){
            // HOW TO PASS THE ITEM HERE IN THE JAVASCRIPT SECTION
            // FOR EXAMPLE:
            // if (item == undefined) {
            //       alert("item not found");
            //}
        });

block content
    .container
        if (item != undefined)
            .card
                h1.text-center #{title}
                form(method='POST' action='/items/addItem' class='needs-validation' enctype='multipart/form-data' novalidate)
                    .card
                        .card-header
                            i.icon-calendar
                            h4.panel-title Item Name
                        .card-body
                            .form-row
                                input#validationItemName.form-control(name='itemName' type='text' placeholder='Item name' required='')
                                div.invalid-feedback Item name is required!
                                // HOW TO PASS item.item_name TO THIS INPUT BOX
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass the value of `item.item_name` into the input element just leave out the quotes and this will render on the server:

```
input#validationItemName.form-control(value= item.item_name name='itemName'...
```