# How can I access the DOM elements in PUG

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I have an index page rendered from Express and there is a variable named 'data' passed by express.
I would like to draw a graph within the template using mdbootstrap with the data object passed by express.

I would like to do something like this:

```
canvas#lineChart

- function plot(data){
-   var context = document.getElementById("lineChart").getContext("2d");
-   var myChart = new Chart(context, data);
- }

- plot(data)
```

But it shows that

> Can't get property 'getElementById' of undefined

What can I do about it?

Comment: node js or web browser html ??

Comment: The DOM doesn't exist when Pug is compiling and running any code block javascript. If you want the javascript to run in a browser where the DOM does exist, put it in a `<script>` tag.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node JS Pass variables to pug template's JavaScript and html sections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53254740/node-js-pass-variables-to-pug-templates-javascript-and-html-sections)

Comment: Not really but am going to  try it out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't access DOM in nodejs. Since it is not have browser ENV. You can use [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) to load html on chrom browser.

If you just working with template string in nodejs. Use a module like a cheerio. To work on DOM like structure in node js.

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const $ = cheerio.load('<h2 class="title">Hello world</h2>')

$('h2.title').text('Hello there!')
$('h2').addClass('welcome')

$.html()
//=> <html><head></head><body><h2 class="title welcome">Hello there!</h2></body></html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I don't think you got my question.I have understood that the DOM can not be accessed on compile time, but this is not the solution that I need.